# Why do I see a big difference in loadtime between jMeter and user experience when browsing?

Tags: jmeter, selenium-chromedriver, page-load-time

My problem is that I see the load time for a web page element on a test in jMeter @ 200 miliseconds and when browsing, most of the time I get 3 or 4 seconds, in the condition where the size in bytes is @ 331000.

I must mention that I cleared the cache and cookies for each iteration and I inserted also the constant timer between the steps.

The searching an id  is the actual case described previously.

```
var pkg = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium); 
var wait_ui = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait);
var wait = new wait_ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 5000);

WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()

var searchBox = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id("140:0;p"));

searchBox.click();
searchBox.sendKeys("1053606032");
searchBox.sendKeys(org.openqa.selenium.Keys.ENTER);

WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

I expected to see the same load time results, but maybe an option would be if I  wait until some elements on the search results page are visible. But I cannot bring an argument why is this difference. I had another case where the page loads in 10 seconds in Chrome and in jMeter Test Results 300 miliseconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with wait until for a specific element which loads as close as the page load.

Below is another try for the same. Use the below code and check if this helps:-

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('http://jmeter-plugins.org')

//(JavascriptExecutor)WDS.browser.executeScript("return document.readyState").toString().equals("complete")
WDS.browser.executeScript("return document.readyState").toString().equals("complete")
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

For me without execute script page loads in 3 sec and with executeScript it loads in 7 sec..while in browser that loads in around 7.57sec..

Hope this helps.

Comment: It was very useful. I got the results I wanted. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Glad to hear that.